# Pipe a file of bytes to C++program, via Linux and read byte-by-byte?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, cin

Is there a way to pipe a file of (bytes- obviously) in to a C++ application on Linux. However, rather than just use `getline()` I would like to read each byte only once. For example I don't want to use `getline()` because it would read all the bytes up to the '\n' and then I would also have to re-read the bytes given to me via `getline()`, so the bytes are read twice. I would just like to "iterate" through each byte once.

What would be the best-performing technique, to read PAGE_SIZE bytes at a go? Any example code is most welcome!

Comment: I don't understand where the bytes are being read twice...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth when you call getLine() the bytes would be traversed once (otherwise how does it know where the '\n' is) and then I will traverse the bytes for a second time applying my application logic.

Comment: @H2CO3 how does fgetc() compare with the read() suggestion below?

Comment: @user997112 It does almost exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that `std::cin` is of type `std::istream`. You can use standard `get()` on it to retrieve a `char` at a time with:

```
char nextVal = std::cin.get();
```

To read `PAGE_SIZE` bytes at a go, use `read()` instead:

```
char *buffer = new char[PAGE_SIZE];
std::cin.read(buffer, PAGE_SIZE);
```

Remember to always check error conditions and EOF after reading.

Comment: However, this is manually implementing what Linux memory-mapped files achieve.  So if performance is an issue, that may well be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for this- would you agree reading PAGE_SIZE bytes at a time would be the most efficient? Would there be a "neat" way of handling the last read (where there wouldnt necessarily be PAGE_SIZE bytes remaining)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth agreed, but I have been told the input needs to be "piped" in to the application from (presumably) terminal.

Comment: Yes, it is more efficient, because it translates to a single system call to read, instead of `PAGE_SIZE` separate ones. To handle the last read, you can use `readsome()` instead of `read()`: it returns the number of bytes actually stored in the array: on the last call, it will be less than `PAGE_SIZE`.

Comment: Any response regarding the other answer here, saying that read() would introduce another buffer?